# Why are there separate check-ins for flights to Israel?

Tags: check-in, israel

I noticed that on many occasions there was a separate check-in line for flights to Israel.

The most recent one is right next to me: at CDG there is a line for everyone and a separate check-in for Tel Aviv (both Easy Jet).

What are the reasons for this? (I saw that case at numerous occasions in different countries, and the singled out flight was always to Israel).

I belive that this has something to do with security, but they are not the only country with such issues.

Comment: It’s been a long time, but last time I saw a dedicated check-in area for flights fo Israel they were going through all their bags before check-in. Not sure if the policy applies/applied to all flights go Israel or specifically El Al flights.

Comment: Note that at least during some time periods, flights to the US were also segregated, with additional questioning before one was allowed go join the queue for check-in. It’s all security-related.

Comment: Extra security.

Comment: Not sure what your actual question is here. Incidentally, security is lighter than for Israel-bound flights but flights to the US are often singled out to. There is an extra questioning step before you reach the check-in desk and sometimes additional luggage checks at the gate.

Comment: @Relaxed I think the underlying question is "why is it only Israel that requires additional security when flying there".  Israel also apparently uses psychological profiling of pax via casual conversations.  But I have no experience in that as I have never flown there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's not a practical travel question.

Comment: @PeterM Yes but that's not exactly true (cf. US-bound flights), not a practical question, and the answer is already in the question (yet the OP somehow doubts it).

Comment: @Relaxed: my question is indeed why Israel is singled out, especially outside of Israel (that is: on a French airport the check-in will be done by the airport staff and not some specialized Israeli customs officers). I am not sure how this is not a travel question.

Comment: @WoJ It's not a *practical* travel question. It doesn't change anything for you as a traveller. In actual fact, check-in is not typically performed by airport staff anymore but by a ground handling business (“assistance en escale”), several of which operate in Paris. It's not always as visible as the extra checks for Israel-bound flights but they operate based on the requirements set by airlines and by destination countries, including luggage inspections, visa or documentation checks, passenger screening or data exchange (APIS) so the exact procedure always differs.

Comment: Israel is singled out based on the requirement the country sets on inbound flight and on a different risk assessment from either the airline or the local authorities. In many cases, flights operated by El Al also get extra protection by the police (e.g. extra barriers and police presence before checking in Schiphol, [on-tarmac escort by a police vehicle in Germany](https://aviation.startbilder.de/bild/Airport~Deutschland~Dusseldorf+-+DUS/56685/el-al-767-2004x-eaf-mit-begleitschutz-der.html)).

Comment: The ground handling contractor might be a separate business with local staff but if the airlines says "passengers with status get priority treatment” or the country says “passengers without a visa are not allowed to board”, they will simply implement those rules. The assumption that all flights get treated the same based only on local law is just mistaken and once you realise this, there isn't much left to explain.

Comment: This is a perfectly reasonable question not meaningfully different than the hundreds, if not thousands, of questions on the site that start with "Why."

Comment: It's not "extra security" but "extra security theater". And the reason it applies to flights to Israel is because Israel says it is mandatory. Many countries (e.g. the USA and Australia) have equally arbitrary (and pointless) mandatory regulations, but they are not so visible as a separate check-in line.

Answer (score 24):

Security.

There have been multiple incidents of flights to Israel bring targeted by terrorists, e.g
[hijacking](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operation_Entebbe), [a missile attack](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/2002_Mombasa_attacks) and more. Attacks on Israeli or Jewish targets worldwide have occurred in recent years, so it's possible that a place bound for Israel will be targeted again.

All flights to Israel have extra security. This generally involves a gate area being closed off, with screening devices for passengers and their luggage, as well as some extra questioning. They will normally not go over all bags, but a slight concern may prompt this (e.g. luggage was left unattended).

I've seen this on multiple European and American airports.

Comment: It doesn't make sense. An airport operator should at minimum guarantee that **all** passengers in the secure area area safe and don't carry any weapon, irregardless of their destination

Comment: But, huh, I have to correct myself. I was thinking only about security lanes (my answer covers MXP but I have seen that also at VNO, MAN). Indeed, in European airports one may reach the check-in counter with a weapon because there is no earlier x-ray

Comment: @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ Security measures rarely make sense. Most of them are just theater, pretending they are going to stop something being repeated but ignoring the fact that *successful* security breaches often involve doing something new for the *first* time.

Comment: @alephzero You're forgetting that the point of all such security measures is to reassure passengers that are afraid of flying. They thus tend to address threats that people are the most afraid of. Just by the number of potential casualties,bombing a plane is no more attractive than bombing a train,yet we don't have rigorous security screening on every station. Why? Because people are rarely scared of taking the tube.

Comment: @TooTea Ah, I see you did not travel by train (or metro) in China ;) I also experienced metal detectors used at Russian train stations but ... not always were the officers interested in actually screening the passengers.

Comment: @TooTea, A plane is much more sensitive than a train, due to the simple fact that it's flying and can fall. A bomb that can bring down a plane would cause moderate damage to a part of a train compartment.

Answer (score -14):

### Tell apart Jews/Israeli from Arabs

Because they don't like to meet each other

This was the exact answer by a security scrutiny operator at [MXP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Malpensa_Airport) when I last traveled. Last year I was switching from BGY to MXP Terminal 1 and I noticed that there was a separate security lane for "US and Israel flights only". However: 1) no special machinery was present at those security lanes and 2) the screening area entered the same duty-free zone, and the path to the gates was common. I actually didn't see a full body scanner in MXP yet, those devices are expensive.

I kindly asked one of the guards what is the reason airports *often* provide separate lanes to Israel, and if extra security is present or not. That person replied like I said above. Americans don't like Arabs, Arabs don't like Jews. There is risk of a **fight** in the queue.

Worse, there is no separate queue at outbound passport control, so that would only be a matter of schedules.

Of course, that was the answer of an operator to a passenger. Though I want to believe them, it is possible that Israel lanes operate with extra screening but operators won't tell. Makes no sense to me. The screening should be the same for all passengers. Airport operators must make sure that no passenger is carrying weapons or offensive things.

Suppose for a second that an airport has a security lane where chances of bringing a gun in the safe zone are increased. You know what...

Comment: No offense to the good Americans that make Arab friends ❤

Comment: Incorrect. Anyone flying to Israel will be directed to the same check-in regardless of religion or ethnicity

Comment: Even if there’s no additional “machinery”, that doesn’t prevent additional questioning, and hand searches.

Comment: @asherbar there could be a misunderstanding. Separate (security) lanes are according to destination. I mentioned "US and Israel **flights** only" in Malpensa. Of course Arabs are mostly banned from entering Israel

Comment: Perhaps that's the answer that security officer gave, but it doesn't make any sense. If this was to separate Jews from Arabs, shouldn't be there a separate lane for the [20 percent Arab citizens of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arab_citizens_of_Israel)? Perhaps that security officer didn't know that they exist (and perhaps you didn't either, @usr-local-ΕΨΗΕΛΩΝ)?

Comment: That was clearly a bulls##t off-the-cuff answer from a poorly educated employee.  It is absolutely *not* the real reason.

Comment: That makes no sense whatsoever. The line is according to the destination. Meaning that both Arabs and Jews going to Israel will attend the same line. How is that achieving the goal of "telling them apart" because "they don't like each other"?